# CSS text background-clip very different on Firefox than on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Chrome: the desired effect
[image]

Firefox: what is happening
[image]

Code:

```
  background-color: Red;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0px 3px 3px;
```

Thoughts??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though -moz-background-clip is supported in firefox. The 'text' value is not supported. You are going to have to go with another solution for non webkit browsers.

Example:
http://nimbupani.com/using-background-clip-for-text-with-css-fallback.html